# R cannot import data through bigrquery package - !self$finished is not TRUE

Tags: bigrquery

when trying to pull larger datasets from my GBQ account, I hit this error message:
`Error in pb_tick(self, private, len, tokens) : !self$finished is not TRUE`

The table I am querying is ~105GB and the same SQL query works fine in the GBQ console. It's not a very complex query, just asking for 200MB of data. Query below. I can't find anything related to this error message, hoping y'all can help out

R code:

```
library(bigrquery) 
project_id <- "xxx-xxx-xxx" # put your project ID here 
sql <- "SELECT * FROMxxx-xxx-xxx.Conversion_Records.Conversion_records_2018_9_to_10`
WHERE event_time >= '2018-09-16 00:00:01'
AND lower(campaign_name) like 'camp_a%'
AND lower(vendor_name) = 'vendor_a';"

gbq <- query_exec(sql, project = project_id, use_legacy_sql = FALSE, max_pages = Inf)
```

Comment: This error is from a progress bar in the `progress` package. Can you try `query_exec()` with `quiet = TRUE`?

Comment: It also looks like `query_exec()` is [deprecated](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/bigrquery/versions/1.0.0/topics/query_exec), can you try the new function?

Comment: Thanks - I had better luck with the new function:
`dat <- bq_project_query(x = project_id, query = sql)

bq_table_fields(dat)

gbq <- bq_table_download(dat)
`